# illegal string body character after dollar sign for bash command in jenkinsfile

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I'm running a jenkins pipeline and has this line:
`def CheckChartDir = sh (script: " git rev-parse remotes/origin/${env.ghprbTargetBranch}:chart &> /dev/null ; echo $? ", returnStdout: true).trim()`
and when i tried it .. i got this error:
`illegal string body character after dollar sign; solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 167, column 91. origin/${env.ghprbTargetBranch}:chart&>` 
I don't know what's the issue and how to fix it .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the expansion of "**${env.ghprbTargetBranch}**" is not as long as that string, **Column 91** suggests that the issue is with the **$?**, not the earlier variable that already has braces.

I suggest you replace

```
echo $?
```

by

```
echo \"\$\?\"
```

and see how it reacts.

Comment: But this won’t echo the result code of that command .i need to get the result of that command

Comment: Try "set -x" and examine the output.

Comment: how i can do this ? can you copy for me the whole command ?

Comment: Replace ...  **script: " git**  ... by ...  **script: "set -x ; git** .